# Is this recurrence relation correct?

Tags: recurrence-relations

from [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Solve-Recurrence-Relations)

Consider the sequence $5, 0, -8, -17, -25, -30, \dots$ given by the recursion shown.

$$a_0 = 5 \\
  a_n = a_{n - 1} + n^2 - 6$$

Is this correct?  I can calculate $a_1$:

$$a_1 = 5 + 1^2 - 6  = 0$$

But i can't calculate $a_2$:

$$a_2 = 0 + 2^2 - 6  =  -2$$

But $-2 \not= -8$  (I also get a mistake when $n>2$)

What am i doing wrong? Or Is there a mistake on that website?

Comment: Given the recurrence formula, your computations are correct. And the initial sequence you gave is not this one.

Comment: That web site is incorrect. $a_n-a_{n-1}=n^2-6$. For $n\ge3$ difference is supposed to be positive. Which it is not in the sequence given.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take out the heavy machinery... the recurrence is:
$$
a_{n + 1} = a_n + (n + 1)^2 - 6 = a_n + n^2 + 2 n - 5
$$
We also have $a_0 = 5$.

Define the ordinary generating function:
$$
A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
$$
By the properties of ordinary generating functions, we get ($D$ is $\frac{d}{dz}$):
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} = A(z) + ((zD)^2 + 2 z D - 5) \frac{1}{1 - z}
$$
Solving for $A(z)$ and expanding in partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = 11 \cdot \frac{1}{1 - z} 
         - 5 \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
         - 3 \frac{1}{(1 - z)^3}             
         + 2 \frac{1}{(1 - z)^4}
$$
Thus the solution is given by:
$$
\begin{align*}
a_n &= 11 
        - 5 \cdot (-1)^n \binom{-2}{n} 
        - 3 \cdot (-1)^n \binom{-3}{n}
        + 2 \cdot (-1)^n \binom{-4}{n} \\
    &= \frac{2 n^3 + 3 n^2 - 35 n + 30}{6}
\end{align*}
$$
This because $\binom{-k}{n} = (-1)^n \binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$.

[Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)'s help with the algebra is gratefully acknowledged. Typoes and brainoes are entirely my fault.

Comment: closed form calculation (after recurrence relation) can be done in a more elegant way : $a_{n} = a_{n-1} + p(n-1)$ , $a_{n-1} = a_{n-2} + p(n-2)$ .. $a_{1} = a_{0} + p(0)$, $p$ being the quadratic polynomial. Now just add all these equations, and only $a_{n}$ survives on LHS with a cubic on the RHS

Comment: @piyush, yes. But the technique above is applicable much more generally.